# iOS IMA SDK - Video not resuming after closing the In-app browser (After clicking Learn More)

Tags: vast, imasdk

I am using IMA SDK to play VAST ads. The ad video plays perfect but when I click on 'Learn More' button in the video ad, which opens in-app browser. After click on 'Done' in that window, the video ad is not resuming. Should i add something here to resume it ? I believe the SDK would handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Need implement IMAWebOpenerDelegate

```
...
var adsManager: IMAAdsManager!
...

extension ViewController: IMAWebOpenerDelegate {

func webOpenerDidClose(inAppBrowser webOpener: NSObject!) {
        print("closed")
        adsManager.resume()
    }
    
    func webOpenerDidOpen(inAppBrowser webOpener: NSObject!) {
        // Do something
    }
    func webOpenerWillClose(inAppBrowser webOpener: NSObject!) {
        // Do something
    }
    
    func webOpenerWillOpen(inAppBrowser webOpener: NSObject!) {
        // Do something
    }
    func webOpenerWillOpenExternalBrowser(_ webOpener: NSObject!) {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have the user resume the Ad when your app regains focus. Keep in mind that a user might forget that the app was in the background so a user might be surprised to hear the app blaring an Ad once in focus.

1. Add a play button overlay on the IMA player.
2. Add a trigger to the button

   ```
   func playBtnPress(){

     // make sure adsManager is initialized
   guard let adsManager = adsManager else {
       requestAds() // initialize adsManager
       return
   }

   // resume playback if paused
   if !adsManager.adPlaybackInfo.isPlaying {
       adsManager.resume()
   }
   }
   ```

3.Add `IMAAdsManagerDelegate`

```
    func adsManager(_ adsManager: IMAAdsManager!, didReceive event: IMAAdEvent!) {

    if event.type == IMAAdEventType.LOADED {
        // When the SDK notifies us that ads have been loaded, play them.
        // hide play button first
        playButton.isHidden = true
        adsManager.start()
    }
    
    if event.type == IMAAdEventType.RESUME {
        // When the SDK notifies us that ads playback has resumed from a pause
        // hide play button
        playButton.isHidden = true
    }
    
    if event.type == IMAAdEventType.PAUSE {
        // When the SDK notifies us that ads playback is paused 
        // Show play button
        playButton.isHidden = false
    }
    
    if event.type == IMAAdEventType.TAPPED {
        // You can also add allow the user to tap anywhere on the Ad to resume play
        if(!adsManager.adPlaybackInfo.isPlaying) {
            adsManager.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you an also implement the `IMAWebOpenerDelegate ` to listen to resume when the browser closes https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/client-side/clickthrough#listening-for-clickthrough-related-events